# Multiple Markdown FIle Selection in Reveal

Tags: markdown, reveal.js

I am using Reveal.js for my lectures. It works great loading an external markdown file at runtime. Is there a way to set up one master index.html file that allows me to select which external file to load? What I have in mind would be like a table of contents, but each topic would be a separate markdown file. I suspect javascript would be the way to do this, but while I am capable (not expert) with HTML and CSS, I can't write a line of javascript (I can copy, paste and load).

Google was not my friend.

Answer (score 4):

This was bugging me, too, and so I decided to see if I could Google-search and splice my way through this.

The basic Reveal.js `div` looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="reveal">

    <!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
    <div class="slides">

    <section data-markdown="somefile" data-separator="^\n\n\n" data-vertical="^\n\n" data-notes="^Note:">
    </section>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.min.js"></script>

<script>
        // Full list of configuration options available here:
        // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
        Reveal.initialize({
             . . . 
        });

</script>

</body>
```

## Simple Way (Manual Entry of Entire Filename)

We can dynamically set an attribute, e.g. the `data-markdown` field in the `<section>` element with JavaScript. There are two small snags here: we have to do it after the element is created, but before Reveal.js does its entire initialization, otherwise the state of the DOM and Reveal.js's internal state will get out of alignment.  This is easy enough (only showing the changed section):

```
<!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
<div class="slides">

<section id="presentation" data-separator="^\n\n\n" data-vertical="^\n\n" data-notes="^Note:">
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("presentation").setAttribute("data-markdown",prompt("Filename:","default-filename.md"));
</script>
```

When you load the page, you get a small alert/prompt where you enter the **full** filename (relative to the web server root). If you do like I do and use `python -m'SimpleHTTPServer` to run a local webserver directly in the directory with the all the slides, then this isn't too bad.

## Complicated Way (File Chooser Dialog)

The simple way is a nice start, but it isn't quite as convenient as a fully graphical chooser. Luckily, it turns out that we can do that, too. The hard part here is that we have to run the file chooser after the page is fully loaded and rendered, which means we have to do something to get Reveal.js's state lined back up with the DOM. There's a `sync()` method in the API that's supposed to be useful for just such situations, but it doesn't work here for some reason. Instead, we delay Reveal.js's full initialization until we've set the external Markdown file:

```
<body>

    <!-- Choose file button -->
    <input type="file" id="external_md" name="markdown" >

    <div class="reveal">

        <!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
        <div class="slides">

        <section id="presentation" data-separator="^\n\n\n" data-vertical="^\n\n" data-notes="^Note:">
        </section>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectFile(evt) {
            // the file chooser actually returns a list 
            // (in case you enabled multiple selection)
            file = evt.target.files[0].name;
            document.getElementById("presentation").setAttribute("data-markdown",file);
            // now it's time to init!
            delayed_init();
            // remove file selector button
            fileSelector = document.getElementById("external_md");
            fileSelector.parentNode.removeChild(fileSelector);
        }
        document.getElementById('external_md').addEventListener('change',selectFile,false);
        </script>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
    <script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // we have to wrap the init function both to delay it and to make it 
        // easier to call later, all without moving big blocks of code around
        function delayed_init(){
            // Full list of configuration options available here:
            // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration

             Reveal.initialize({
             . . . 
            });
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

That are three change areas:
1. Addition of an `<input>` element to drive the file chooser.
2. Extra Javascript in the middle.
3. Wrapping the call to `Reveal.initialize()` with a dummy function to delay initialization.

All of this worked for me with the current release of Reveal.js (`9cf7de54b8f`). Please note that I keep all of the Reveal.js stuff in a subfolder `reveal.js`, so you may need to adjust the paths above accordingly.